# Where to publish artifacts in available maven repositories for commercial purpose?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jboss, jcenter

In my organization we planned to deliver artifacts to customers via maven repository, as it is for **commercial purposes**, we don’t want to share a source / related links. Kindly suggest the best -suited approach from below,

1. Publishing artifacts in [maven central](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/)
2. Publishing in any available public repositories ([Atlassian](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/working-with-maven/#atlassian-maven-repositories), [Jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter), [JBoss](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-11377), etc.)
3. Maintaining own public maven repositories. ( https://mvnrepository.com/repos ) from the listed ones.
   I have been in confusion to proceed with the available approaches. Kindly share your suggestions.

Comment: Note, though, that "without source code" usually does not matter too much as it is easy to decompile Java - unless you obfuscate it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the Artifactory OSS, this will give you the Maven repositories needed and stores the jars/wars/aars etc into and then you can give the users the Artifactory link for these jars so that they can download it. Refer to this [link](https://jfrog.com/open-source/) on how to install and work with Maven repos.